# gridSearch performance measure effect

Tags: python, regression, hyperparameters

I have an assignment and it asks me to:

> Improve  the performance of the models from the previous stepwith
>   hyperparameter tuning and select a final optimal model using grid
>   search based on a  metric (or metrics) that you choose. Choosing an
>   optimal model for a given task (comparing multiple regressors on a
>   specific domain) requires selecting performance measures, for example,
>   R2(coefficient of determination) and/or RMSE  (root mean squared
>   error) to compare the model performance.

I used this code for hyperparameter tuning:

```
model_example = GradientBoostingRegressor()
parameters = {'learning_rate': [0.1, 1], 
              'max_depth': [5,10]}

model_best = GridSearchCV(model_example,
                          param_grid=parameters,
                          cv=2,scoring='r2').fit(X_train_new,y_train_new)
model_best.best_estimator_
```

I found the learning rate=0.1 and max_dept=5
I have chosen `scoring='r3'` as a performance measure but it doesn't have any effect on my model accuracy when I used this code for providing my best model:

```
my_best_model = GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,
                                          max_depth=5).fit(X_train_new,y_train_new)
my_best_model.score(X_train_new,y_train_new)
```

Do you know what's wrong with my work?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a `random_state` as a parameter of your `GradientBoostingRegressor()`. For example, `GradientBoostingRegressor(random_state=1)`.

The model will then produce the same results on the same data. Without that parameter, there's an element of randomness that makes it difficult to compare different model fits.

Setting a random state on the train-test-split will also help with this.

Comment: still nothing changes when I add scoring='r2'